# How to estimate FPGA utilization for designing a work a like core?

Tags: reverse-engineering, fpga, utilization

I was considering some older generation FPGA's to interface with a legacy system.  So I want a good way of estimating how much space is necessary to replace an ASIC given its transistor count.

- Does Verilog versus VHDL affect the utilization?  (According to one of our contractors it affects the timing, so utilization seems likely.)
- What effect do different vendor's parts have on it?  (Actel's architecture is significantly different from Xilinx', for example. I expect some "weighting" based on this.)

Answer (score 1):

[This discussion originally from comp.arch.fpga](http://www.fpgarelated.com/usenet/fpga/show/80887-1.php) seems to indicate that it's pretty complicated, including factors such as what space vs. speed tradeoffs you've asked the VHDL (or verilog) compiler to make, etc. When you consider that VHDL is source code and an FPGA implementation of it is object code, you'll see why it's not straightforward.

["FPGA vs. ASIC"](http://www.octera.com/tips_and_techniques/fpga_vs_asic.php4) notes that "a design created to work well on an FPGA is usually horrible on an ASIC and a design created for an ASIC may not work at all on an FPGA (certainly at the original frequency)".

A Google search for [FPGA ASIC gates](http://www.google.com/search?q=fpga+asic+gates) may have more useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog vs. VHDL has little real difference on speed or utilization.  It is more related to amount of code you have to type (more for VHDL) and strong vs weak-typing.

The marketing gates for FPGA vendors are inflated.  Altera vs. Xilinx are similar utilization.  Look at memories (if memory intensive) and number of flip-flops; that will likely be good enough.

Consider what a similar core requires, for example if you need to do an error-coding core, look at a Reed-Solomon core.

Comment: Yeah, I know gates != constant * transistors.  I wish there was some sort of benchmark for FPGA - "Drystone Gates" so you could do an apples to apples comparison.